# EXCEPTION_THROWN [0]|System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting System.Query Exception for my code below. Can anyone help me to rectify the same.

```
     public void updateOpportunityStage(){
        Set<Id> setIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Order> orderOldMap =(Map<Id,Order>)oldMap;
        Map<Id,Order> orderNewMap=(Map<Id,Order>)newMap;
        Set<Opportunity>  updateOppties=new Set<Opportunity>();
        DateTime statusChange= System.now()-90;

        for (Order childObj : (List<Order>) newList) {
            if(childObj.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'Recipient' && childObj.Record_Type_Dev_Name__c == 'Upgrade_Order'){ 
            setIds.add(childObj.AccountId);

            }
        }
        if (setIds.isEmpty()) { return; }

        Map<ID, Account> parentAccts = new Map<Id, Account>(
                                          [select id, Upgrade_Order_Booked_Date__c, Upgrade_Order_Status__c, Order_Cancellation_Reason__c,Upgrade_Order_Number__c,Order_Cancellation_Date__c,
                                          (select id, Name, Booked_Date__c, Status ,Order_Cancellation_Reason__c,Oracle_Order_Number__c,Order_Cancellation_Date__c
                                            from Orders where Account_Record_Type_Name__c = 'Recipient'
                                             AND Record_Type_Dev_Name__c = 'Upgrade_Order') 
                                           from Account where id in :setIds]);

        System.debug('updateOrderUpgrade parentAccts: ' + parentAccts);


        Map<Account, Order> accountToLatestOrder = new Map<Account, Order>();

        for (Account acc : parentAccts.values()) {
            System.debug('orderOldMap acc: ' + acc);

            System.debug('orderOldMap acc1: ' + acc.orders);
            if (acc.orders.isEmpty() == false) {
                System.debug('orderOldMap acc2: ' + acc);
                 System.debug('orderOldMap acc2: ' + acc.orders);
                accountToLatestOrder.put(acc,acc.orders);
                System.debug('orderOldMap acc3: ' + acc);
            }
            System.debug('orderOldMap acc: ' + acc);
        }



      for(Account acc : [select id, Upgrade_Order_Booked_Date__c, Upgrade_Order_Status__c, Order_Cancellation_Reason__c,Upgrade_Order_Number__c,Order_Cancellation_Date__c,
                                    (select Id,Name,closedate,amount,StageName,Oracle_Order_Number__c,Status_Last_Changed_On__c
                                     from opportunities where Record_Type_Dev_Name__c='Upgrade_Opportunity') 
                                    from Account where id in : setIds]){
                              System.debug('orderOldMap acc: ' + acc);          

                            System.debug('orderOldMap  orders1' + accountToLatestOrder);
                             System.debug('orderOldMap  orders2' + accountToLatestOrder.values());           

                    for (Order orders : accountToLatestOrder.values()) {

                     System.debug('orderOldMap  orders' + parentAccts);

                     for(Opportunity opps : acc.opportunities){
                                        System.debug('orderOldMap.get(orders.Id): ' + orderOldMap.get(orders.Id));


                     if(opps.StageName<>'Upgrade-Closed Won'  && orders.Status!=orderOldMap.get(orders.Id).Status && orders.Status=='Cancelled') {

     opps.StageName='Upgrade - Closed Lost'; 

    opps.Oracle_Order_Number__c=orders.Oracle_Order_Number__c;

 }

else if((opps.StageName<>'Upgrade-Closed Won'&&(opps.StageName=='Upgrade - Closed Lost' && opps.Status_Last_Changed_On__c>= statusChange))&& orders.Status!=orderOldMap.get(orders.Id).Status && orders.Status=='Closed'){                      
opps.StageName='Upgrade-Closed Won';
                                        opps.Oracle_Order_Number__c=orders.Oracle_Order_Number__c;
}
System.debug('updateOpportunityStage Opportunity: ' + opps);  
updateOppties.add(opps);
}
}
}

List<Opportunity> updateopps=new List<Opportunity>(updateOppties);
update updateopps;
  }
```

I checked debug logs and assume the problem is with below line

```
accountToLatestOrder.put(acc,acc.orders);
```

My requirement is to fetch orders from accounts where order record type=Upgrade Order and when any one of the upgrade order changed status to 'Cancelled' then all of the opportunities(where oppty record type=upgrade oppty and stage is not equals to Closed Won) linked to the same account to which upgrade orders are linked will change status to Closed Lost.

Comment: this error occurs when a soql query is assigned to singleton variable instead of a list.  Are you sure it isn't in the trigger code that runs after you update the Opportunities?  BTW - you should use [edit] to reformat your post so the code is properly indented

Comment: @cropredy-Thanks for your response. Yes you are right it happens when I am trying to update opportunity/es. And I am also aware when this kind of error arises.But I am unable to resolve this. Kindly note I am running this method in before update call.Any help will be greatly appreciated.Many thanks

Comment: Look in the code fired by the update Lopo trigger.  The debug log should give you a line number in the relevant class/trigger

Comment: @cropredy-I chcked in debug logs and found something like this EXCEPTION_THROWN [0]|System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject.No line no is mentioned for this service class. Actually we are using Event-Dispatcher trigger model where we have one trigger one dispatcher and one service class.This method is written inside service class.Kindly help

Comment: Wrap your code with a try catch.  In the catch block, display the exception variable getStackTraceString()

Answer (score 1):

Orders in parentAccts query can be more than 1 use list while defining the map. This should solve the error you mentioned in title.

```
Map<ID, Account> parentAccts = new Map<Id, Account>(
                                      [select id, Upgrade_Order_Booked_Date__c, Upgrade_Order_Status__c, Order_Cancellation_Reason__c,Upgrade_Order_Number__c,Order_Cancellation_Date__c,
                                      (select id, Name, Booked_Date__c, Status ,Order_Cancellation_Reason__c,Oracle_Order_Number__c,Order_Cancellation_Date__c
                                        from Orders where Account_Record_Type_Name__c = 'Recipient'
                                         AND Record_Type_Dev_Name__c = 'Upgrade_Order') 
                                       from Account where id in :setIds]);

Map<Account, List<Order>> accountToLatestOrder = new Map<Account,List<Order>>();
```

And you also should change the line where you looped over orders because you are looping on accounts and accountToLatestOrder.values() have lists of all accounts' orders.

```
 for (Order orders : accountToLatestOrder.get(acc.Id).values())
```